# Using <div> as a parent element

Tags: html, css

I have recently been following tutorials on html and css. In a lot of these tutorials I see people using tags, such as `<nav>`, `<footer>`, etc..., like this.

```
<someTag class = "someClass">
    <div class = "anotherClass">
        <whatever>

        </whatever>
    </div>
</someTag>
```

However is it not better practice to do something similar to this?

```
<someTag class = "someClass">
    <whatever class = "anotherClass">

    </whatever>
</someTag>
```

My question is why do people use divs in situations like this at all?

Comment: _"My question is why do people use divs in situations like this at all?"_ Because they can

Comment: Is it good practice though to use semantic tags with styling? Or is that the "job" of a `div`? This is probably where opinions kick in. IMO the less divs the better, but then some people like their semantic tags to be entirely independent of styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML standard defines a set of allowed elements, including `NAV`, `FOOTER`, `DIV`, etc.

Arbitrary custom elements are disallowed. You can use them technically, but such HTML document would be formally invalid and potentially not future-proof since there is a probability that your custom elements may be added to the standard in future.

`DIV` is a common container without semantic meaning and should generally be used just to group other elements to apply styles.

Whether to apply styles directly to `DIV` or to elements it contains, depends on specific situation. If it was needed to define a golden rule, it would probably be something like this:

> `DIV` should contain at least one descendant level marked-up as a
>   semantic (i. e. not `DIV` or `SPAN`) element.
>
> If a `DIV` contains just inline elements or pure text,
>   this typically indicates that markup is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The div element is a generic container that should be used when there is no other more semantic one (such as section, nav, header, etc.). Typically it's used as a hook for styling.

https://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-div-element

> The div element has no special meaning at all. It represents its
>   children. It can be used with the class, lang, and title attributes to
>   mark up semantics common to a group of consecutive elements.
>
> Authors are strongly encouraged to view the div element as an element
>   of last resort, for when no other element is suitable. Use of more
>   appropriate elements instead of the div element leads to better
>   accessibility for readers and easier maintainability for authors.